# React Native - Can't get data from asp.net web api

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, expo

I'm building an app using React Native with Expo and an ASP.Net Web API.

I'm using two computers: one I published the Web API on it and using it as a server which has the **IP 192.168.1.9** ,

and the other one with **IP 192.168.1.6** I'm using for developing.

The problem is when I ping the server computer I get a reply and when I use postman I get the data I requested,
[image: using postman to test API]
[image: pinging the server computer]

but when I run the app using Expo on my Android Phone, the request enters the catch and returns an error.
Here is the code:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.1.9/trainlast/api/Login';
    fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then(response => { response.json(); })
        .then(users => {
            this.setState({ allUsers: users });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error getting users :: ', error));
```

[image: catching the fetch error]

I have tried everything I could possibly think of, but no use.

Can someone tell me what the problem is? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `Accept` and `Content-Type` of headers.

And get the correct value for the object.

```js
var url = 'http://192.168.1.9/trainlast/api/Login';
    fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ allUsers: res.Username });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error getting users :: ', error));
```